# Connecting host USB-A to client USB-C

Tags: windows, usb, display, adapter, thunderbolt

I have a  [new monitor](https://www.samsung.com/us/business/support/owners/product/cj791-series-c34J791wtn/) which acts as a USB hub, taking input from things like mice and carrying them to the computer. However, all of its upstream outputs are Thunderbolt 3 / USB-C. My motherboard doesn't take USB-C input, but I have a C → A cable. However, when I plug it in, Windows tells me that the device is unrecognized.

[image: Diagram of the connection]

How can I get Windows to recognize the USB-C device and get the keyboard+mouse to work?

Comment: Please provide the exact make and model of the monitor.

Comment: It's a [Samsung CJ791](https://www.samsung.com/us/business/support/owners/product/cj791-series-c34J791wtn/) monitor. I'll add that to the question description too.

Comment: This is odd. A Type-C hub port should be recognized by USB PC host. Are you sure that you have a right "a C → A cable"? Did you try your cable with any known-good Type-C device, with something like a mass storage device (USB-to-SATA or USB-to NVMe device)? Did you try a different C-A cable?

Comment: Yes, I know the C to A cable works because I used it with my phone with my computer. I tested transferring some files back and forth, which worked fine. And I tried 2 different cables of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201906/20190619123812600/BN46-00711A-Eng_for_India.pdf) for your monitor, you will find a section called "Connecting the Product to a PC as a USB hub."  In that section, you will read that you must connect the computer and the monitor with a USB C connection.

Therefore, using a type A to type C connection will not work.